# The property that det(A) = prod of A's eigenvalues, and tr(A) = sum of A's eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace

Do these two properties fail to be true, if A's characteristic polynomial fails to split?

If so, then do we usually work in a vector space with the ground field = $\mathbb{C}$, when we want to use these two equations?

Thanks,

Comment: If you have $(x^2+1)(x-1)(x+1)$ as your characteristic polynomial, then the determinant of $A$ is still the product of the eigenvalues in $\Bbb{R}$ because the eigenvalues in $\Bbb{C}$ have a product of $1$ and the trace of $A$ is still the sum of the eigenvalues in $\Bbb{R}$ because the eigenvalues in $\Bbb{C}$ have a sum of $0$.

Comment: In $x^2+1$, the roots are $i$ and $-i$, so they have a product of $1$. However, I was just trying to give one example. Obviously, this won't always happen. For example, if you have the characteristic polynomial of $(x^2+2)(x+1)(x-1)$, then the product of the roots is $2$, so the product of the eigenvalues of $\Bbb{R}$ will not be the determinant. On the other hand, if you have a characteristic polynomial with complex coefficients, then you must've had complex numbers in the matrix to begin with, so it splits anyways.

Comment: @NobleMushtak, I don't follow.  In your second comment, how do you even know what the determinant will be?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "the product of the complex roots is $2$." However, you find the determinant by taking the product of all of the real and complex eigenvalues, which is not the same as the product of all of real eigenvalues because the product of the complex eigenvalues is not $1$ like in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an irreducible degree $2$ monic polynomial over the reals it is possible to find a $2\times 2$ matrix having the given polynomial as its characteristic polynomial.

Take $x^2-2x+2$ as the polynomial. A matrix having it as its characteristic polynomial is the [“companion matrix”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 \\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix has no real eigenvalue, so the sum of the real eigenvalues is $0$ and the product is $1$ (this is the convention for the empty sum and product); however the trace is $2$ and the determinant is $2$.

If the characteristic polynomial splits completely, then the statement is true.

Comment: Awesome answer, @egreg - thanks for confirming.